# Single vs multiple database connection performance in a single workflow

Tags: performance, database-design, architecture, database-connection, software-design

need some software architecture insight on this. Which of the following is more efficient in terms of resource (cpu, memory, database)?

1. Having a single database connection in one flow? (Close connection only after everything is done, including business logic)
2. Having multiple database connections in one flow? (Open then close the database connection immediately after the query is executed)

By business logic, this is where data returned from the query is sanitized, or manipulated according to business rules.

Attaching here is the diagram for visual representation.

UPDATE:

Programming language: PHP (Laravel for web app, Lumen for API)

Database: MySQL

Host: AWS

[image]

Comment: What does it run on?  What language?  Or is this purely theoretical?  Ex. in PHP I would open once, close once.  But that means that the connection is taken until the script is done.  In Java, WebSphere will take care of this through pooling of connections.   At a more theoretical level, if your processing (Business Logic) is not too long, your database should be able to keep that connection open for the process to complete.  But high load could jam your database.  You see?  There are lots of potential issues Depends on your style and DB capacity.

Comment: Nic3500, updated my post and added the programming language used. It will be on PHP (Laravel for the web app, Lumen for the API) while the database to be used is MySQL. All will be in AWS

Comment: In this context I would keep the connection and close it at the end.  Unless of course your processing is very long (above a couple seconds).

Answer (score 1):

opening new connection between your runtime and your database needs your OS to create new socket ( if runtime and database are on the same system this socket probably is linux socket, else this socket is tcp/udp socket)
this socket creation has overhead itself.
so I don't suggest to open and close connections after each database usage.
but there are specific conditions you want do that.
for example your database has a limited number of concurrent connections and you have thousands of long running processes using this connections, maybe in this situation you can use second approach.